# The function that disables a button only takes effect when a function running in parallel with it is active

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have two buttons Start and Next. I want that, initially the Start button is in the enabled state, and the Next button is in the disabled state. After the user clicks on the Start button, a function will run, and when the function is finished, the Next button will switch to the enabled state. I used the following code:

```
<button id="start" onclick="myfunction1" >Start</button>
<button id="next" onclick="myfunction2" disabled="disabled">Next</button>
<script>
function myfunction1(){
  google.script.run.openUrl();
  document.getElementById("start").disabled = true;
  document.getElementById("next").disabled = false;
}
</script>
```

When I click on the Start button, the function `myfunction1()` runs, and at the same time the Start button changes to the disabled state and the Next button changes to the enabled state. However, after the `myfunction()` function completes, the Start button returns to the enabled state and the Next button returns to the disabled state.
I don't know how to solve it. I really need help. Thanks.

Comment: Clicking the button also submits your <form>, and since it doesn't have a method or action attribute, that is essentially like reloading the page, which resets your buttons. A quick fix is to add `type="button"` to your <button> so it no longer submits the form. In the long run though you should use `addEventListener()` instead of `onclick="..."` and call `.preventDefault()` on the event

Comment: Are the buttons inside a `<form>`?

Comment: I added `type="button"` to my `<button>` but still not solved the problem. The button is not inside the `<form>`, it's just above a sidebar.

Comment: *Exactly* what does `google.script.run.openUrl();` do?   Looks like it reloads the page.

Comment: `google.script.run.openUrl()` creates copies of a form in Google drive into multiple forms and places them in the same folder.

Comment: Check your browser's network tab to see what it's doing and when.  Remove all code that enables the start button (except the default html enabled).  If it's still getting enabled, then it's definitely your page being reloaded and it's not in (just) the code you've provided.

Comment: Thanks **freedomn**, it's true that `google.script.run.openUrl()` has something to do with some triggering and doing page reloads. What should I do in this case?